# How to detect word boundaries/estimate words count with audio processing? (w/o speech recognition)

Tags: speech-recognition, web-audio-api, speech-to-text, speech, audio-processing

is it possible to detect word boundaries with basic audio processing offline to get accurate enough WPM* estimate? I think it can be done by detecting pauses (indicates a word boundary). will it be cross-Lingual and work on all languages?

in traditional speech recognition [(not / as opposed to) modern machine/deep learning speech recognition], 
which is considered the easier/solved part, finding the words boundaries or statistically matching them to the correct words?

Sample I've been using: [web page with audio elements](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/addiction/ritalin)*, [audio](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/addiction/ritalin/ADHD_Likelihood%20(new).mp3)

Words boundaries marked on a waveform view in Audacity:
[image]

I will be doing it in the browser using [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) and [AudioNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) from the Web Audio API.

*Words Per Minute

---

*more on what I am doing/have in mind: 
I am [forking](https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed/issues/243) the [Videospeed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk) extension to build extension called "Media Enhancer: Audio/Video Playback speed, Shortcuts & Controls", you can guess the new added functionality from the name, playback speed for audio elements, new keyboard shortcuts, optional calculated WPM estimate (hence why I'm asking this question), and many more for power users me included.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to detect word boundaries with basic audio processing offline to get accurate enough WPM* estimate?

No, it is equivalent to recognizing the words.

There were many algorithms proposed for speaking rate estimation, most of them work just by detecting the phones or even the peaks in the sound, you can check for example here

[Robust Speech Rate Estimation for Spontaneous Speech Dagen Wang and Shrikanth S. Narayanan](http://sail.usc.edu/publications/files/WangTASLP2007%5B2%5D.pdf)

More recent research includes machine learning like this one:

[Online Speaking Rate Estimation Using Recurrent Neural Networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b048/1033003053aea44ac25196051d81f423b0da.pdf)